# Creating an array iterating all the objects in an array of object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I have this JSON structure, I want to create 2 arrays out of this array of JSON. one array having all the values from key "employee only" to ""Annual OOP max / entire famliy" (from each object in JSON array) and 2nd array to have values from key "Primary care doctor visit" to end of the object".

**array 1 = [86.1,30.5,33.2, 291.3, 154.1, 121.2..............13700, "$13,100 family"]** (so for eg "employee only" key from object1 then object2 then till last object, again next key from object 1...till last object)

similarly in array 2 starting from key "Primary care doctor visit" till end of object

**array 2 = ["75% covered after deductible", "$35 copay",35,............, "See HMO provider"]**

How can i achieve this in javascript?

```js
[
  {
    "Provider ID": 0,
    "Broker ID": 16,
    "[Plan name, employee-facing]": "Contribution Plan",
    "employee Only": 86.1,
    "employee + Spouse/Partner": 291.3,
    "employee + Child(ren)": 121.4,
    "employee + Family": 311.9,
    " max contrib. / employee only": "Credited to your HRA:\n$250",
    " max contrib. / employee + dependents": "Credited to your HRA:\n$500",
    "Annual ded. / employee only": 1750,
    "Annual ded. / employee + dependents": 3500,
    "Annual OOP max / per person": 6850,
    "Annual OOP max / entire famliy": 13700,
    "Primary care doctor visit": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Specialist doctor visit": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Virtual doctor visit": "$4 copay Doctor on Demand",
    "Eligible preventive care": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Centers of Excellence": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Urgent care": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Emergency": "$300 copay, then 75% covered after deductible",
    "Hospitalization": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Generic drugs": 4,
    "Brand-name drugs": "$50 or 25% of allowed cost*",
    "Speciality drugs": "$50 or 20% of allowed cost*"
  },
  {
    "Provider ID": 0,
    "Broker ID": 23,
    "[Plan name, employee-facing]": "Premier Plan",
    "employee Only": 30.5,
    "employee + Spouse/Partner": 154.1,
    "employee + Child(ren)": 48.8,
    "employee + Family": 180.8,
    " max contrib. / employee only": "None",
    " max contrib. / employee + dependents": "None",
    "Annual ded. / employee only": 2750,
    "Annual ded. / employee + dependents": 5500,
    "Annual OOP max / per person": 6850,
    "Annual OOP max / entire famliy": 13700,
    "Primary care doctor visit": "$35 copay",
    "Specialist doctor visit": "$75 copay",
    "Virtual doctor visit": "$4 copay Doctor on Demand",
    "Eligible preventive care": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Centers of Excellence": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Urgent care": "$75 copay",
    "Emergency": "$300 copay, then 75% covered after deductible",
    "Hospitalization": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Generic drugs": 4,
    "Brand-name drugs": "$50 or 25% of allowed cost*",
    "Speciality drugs": "$50 or 20% of allowed cost*"
  },
  {
    "Benefit/feature": null,
    "Provider ID": 197,
    "[Plan name, employee-facing]": "Kaiser California Low Option South HMO",
    "employee Only": 33.2,
    "employee + Spouse/Partner": 121.2,
    "employee + Child(ren)": 46.7,
    "employee + Family": 138,
    " max contrib. / employee only": "None",
    " max contrib. / employee + dependents": "None",
    "Annual ded. / employee only": "$1,500 individual",
    "Annual ded. / employee + dependents": "$3,000 family",
    "Annual OOP max / per person": "$6,550 individual",
    "Annual OOP max / entire famliy": "$13,100 family",
    "Eligible preventive care services": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Primary care physician visits": 35,
    "Specialists": 50,
    "Centers of Excellence": "Not available",
    "Virtual doctor visits": "Not available",
    "Hospitalization": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Emergency": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Urgent care": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Generic drugs": 10,
    "Brand-name drugs": 50,
    "Speciality drugs": "See HMO provider"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am not getting how do i do this..nowhere i could get the reference to iterate in this way

Comment: Create an Array with some of the values, check something like [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to explore the Objects within the Array and [play around](https://stackblitz.com/) with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new array out of array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485170/how-to-create-a-new-array-out-of-array-of-objects)

Comment: I don't really see what is the difference in your questions. Please don't post duplicate questions like that and if there is a difference then refer to your previous question and explain what is different

Comment: yes the requirement was slightly different, will take care of it from next time

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [{
    "Provider ID": 0,
    "Broker ID": 16,
    "[Plan name, employee-facing]": "Contribution Plan",
    "employee Only": 86.1,
    "employee + Spouse/Partner": 291.3,
    "employee + Child(ren)": 121.4,
    "employee + Family": 311.9,
    " max contrib. / employee only": "Credited to your HRA:\n$250",
    " max contrib. / employee + dependents": "Credited to your HRA:\n$500",
    "Annual ded. / employee only": 1750,
    "Annual ded. / employee + dependents": 3500,
    "Annual OOP max / per person": 6850,
    "Annual OOP max / entire famliy": 13700,
    "Primary care doctor visit": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Specialist doctor visit": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Virtual doctor visit": "$4 copay Doctor on Demand",
    "Eligible preventive care": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Centers of Excellence": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Urgent care": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Emergency": "$300 copay, then 75% covered after deductible",
    "Hospitalization": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Generic drugs": 4,
    "Brand-name drugs": "$50 or 25% of allowed cost*",
    "Speciality drugs": "$50 or 20% of allowed cost*"
  },
  {
    "Provider ID": 0,
    "Broker ID": 23,
    "[Plan name, employee-facing]": "Premier Plan",
    "employee Only": 30.5,
    "employee + Spouse/Partner": 154.1,
    "employee + Child(ren)": 48.8,
    "employee + Family": 180.8,
    " max contrib. / employee only": "None",
    " max contrib. / employee + dependents": "None",
    "Annual ded. / employee only": 2750,
    "Annual ded. / employee + dependents": 5500,
    "Annual OOP max / per person": 6850,
    "Annual OOP max / entire famliy": 13700,
    "Primary care doctor visit": "$35 copay",
    "Specialist doctor visit": "$75 copay",
    "Virtual doctor visit": "$4 copay Doctor on Demand",
    "Eligible preventive care": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Centers of Excellence": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Urgent care": "$75 copay",
    "Emergency": "$300 copay, then 75% covered after deductible",
    "Hospitalization": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Generic drugs": 4,
    "Brand-name drugs": "$50 or 25% of allowed cost*",
    "Speciality drugs": "$50 or 20% of allowed cost*"
  },
  {
    "Benefit/feature": null,
    "Provider ID": 197,
    "[Plan name, employee-facing]": "Kaiser California Low Option South HMO",
    "employee Only": 33.2,
    "employee + Spouse/Partner": 121.2,
    "employee + Child(ren)": 46.7,
    "employee + Family": 138,
    " max contrib. / employee only": "None",
    " max contrib. / employee + dependents": "None",
    "Annual ded. / employee only": "$1,500 individual",
    "Annual ded. / employee + dependents": "$3,000 family",
    "Annual OOP max / per person": "$6,550 individual",
    "Annual OOP max / entire famliy": "$13,100 family",
    "Eligible preventive care services": "100% covered, no deductible",
    "Primary care physician visits": 35,
    "Specialists": 50,
    "Centers of Excellence": "Not available",
    "Virtual doctor visits": "Not available",
    "Hospitalization": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Emergency": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Urgent care": "75% covered after deductible",
    "Generic drugs": 10,
    "Brand-name drugs": 50,
    "Speciality drugs": "See HMO provider"
  }
]

const array1Keys = [
  "employee Only",
  "employee + Spouse/Partner",
  "employee + Child(ren)",
  "employee + Family",
  " max contrib. / employee only",
  " max contrib. / employee + dependents",
  "Annual ded. / employee only",
  "Annual ded. / employee + dependents",
  "Annual OOP max / per person",
  "Annual OOP max / entire famliy"
]
const array2Keys = ["Primary care doctor visit",
  "Specialist doctor visit",
  "Virtual doctor visit",
  "Eligible preventive care",
  "Centers of Excellence",
  "Urgent care",
  "Emergency",
  "Hospitalization",
  "Generic drugs",
  "Brand-name drugs",
  "Speciality drugs"
]

const array1 = array1Keys.flatMap(key => input.map(obj => obj[key]))
const array2 = array2Keys.flatMap(key => input.map(obj => obj[key]))
console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
```